# How do I make Chrome interpret php? Is there any add-on for this?

Tags: php, google-chrome, web-development-server

I am using xampp to build a database. I have written a file in NotePad++ as a php file and tried to open it in Chrome, and all it did was display all the text, unescaped, contained within the notepad file, instead of executing the contents of the file (which was display a deliberate error message). What happened?

Comment: Does it work with another browser?

Comment: Hey man!
In XAMPP, have you turned on Apache? Also, where have you saved your file? With XAMPP you need to save it in the htdocs folder inside XAMPP. If you are using windows, its C:/xampp/htdocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using xampp so put your files inside the htdocs folder of xampp folder. Then access the page : `localhost/myscript.php` in your browser

Comment: The file is in htdocs. The latter part of your answer showed me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers are not code interpreters. Web servers like Apache or nginx utilize other libraries (in PHP's case its usually PHP-FPM or PHP FastCGI Process Manager). They execute the code and return text which may contain HTML or other content to be displayed to the page which is what the browser gives to you.